# Seat Reservation System two-dimensional array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am tasked to create a seat reservation system using two-dimensional arrays. The program specifications are the ff:

1. Use two-dimensional array with size 7 columns and 5 rows.
2. Seat numbers are populated during run-time and not hard-coded.
3. User is asked to input a seat number.
4. The chosen seat number is replaced by the letter X.
5. Program displays a remark “Seat successfully reserved” when reservation is
   done.
6. The user is not allowed to reserve a previously reserved seat. Display “Seat is
   taken” remarks.
7. The user is not allowed to enter an invalid seat number. Display an error
   message.
8. The program continuously loops.

The program works at the start but when it loops again the next seat number doesn't get reserved and just displays the seat is taken.

The code:

```
public class SeatReservation_Andaya {

    // create 2d array w/ 7 columns and 5 rows
    static int[][] seatArray = new int[5][7];

    // create another array 
    static String[][] stringArray = new String[5][7];

    // declare variables 
    static int seatNum = 1;
    static int i, j;

    static boolean chkData() {  // Method that will check for reservation availability
        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; ++j) {
                if (stringArray[i][j].equals("X")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void replaceWithX(int numRes) {
        // replaces the seat chosen with "X"
        switch (numRes) {
            case 1:
                stringArray[0][0] = "X";
                break;

            case 2:
                stringArray[0][1] = "X";
                break;

            case 3:
                stringArray[0][2] = "X";
                break;

            case 4:
                stringArray[0][3] = "X";
                break;

            case 5:
                stringArray[0][4] = "X";
                break;

            case 6:
                stringArray[0][5] = "X";
                break;

            case 7:
                stringArray[0][6] = "X";
                break;

            case 8:
                stringArray[1][0] = "X";
                break;

            case 9:
                stringArray[1][1] = "X";
                break;

            case 10:
                stringArray[1][2] = "X";
                break;

            case 11:
                stringArray[1][3] = "X";
                break;

            case 12:
                stringArray[1][4] = "X";
                break;

            case 13:
                stringArray[1][5] = "X";
                break;

            case 14:
                stringArray[1][6] = "X";
                break;

            case 15:
                stringArray[2][0] = "X";
                break;

            case 16:
                stringArray[2][1] = "X";
                break;

            case 17:
                stringArray[2][2] = "X";
                break;

            case 18:
                stringArray[2][3] = "X";
                break;

            case 19:
                stringArray[2][4] = "X";
                break;

            case 20:
                stringArray[2][5] = "X";
                break;

            case 21:
                stringArray[2][6] = "X";
                break;

            case 22:
                stringArray[3][0] = "X";
                break;

            case 23:
                stringArray[3][1] = "X";
                break;

            case 24:
                stringArray[3][2] = "X";
                break;

            case 25:
                stringArray[3][3] = "X";
                break;

            case 26:
                stringArray[3][4] = "X";
                break;

            case 27:
                stringArray[3][5] = "X";
                break;

            case 28:
                stringArray[3][6] = "X";
                break;

            case 29:
                stringArray[4][0] = "X";
                break;

            case 30:
                stringArray[4][1] = "X";
                break;

            case 31:
                stringArray[4][2] = "X";
                break;

            case 32:
                stringArray[4][3] = "X";
                break;

            case 33:
                stringArray[4][4] = "X";
                break;

            case 34:
                stringArray[4][5] = "X";
                break;

            case 35:
                stringArray[4][6] = "X";
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create scanner tool
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // declare values of int array 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                seatArray[i][j] = seatNum;
                seatNum++;
            }
        }

        // puts int array values into string
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                stringArray[i][j] = Integer.toString(seatArray[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // prints the array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                System.out.print(stringArray[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // loops reservation system 
        while (true) {
            // asks for seat number
            System.out.print("Enter seat number to reserve: ");

            // reads input
            int numRes = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());

            // check if input is invalid
            if (numRes > 35 || numRes <1) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID SEAT NUMBER");
            } else {
                // checks if seat is reserved
                if (chkData()) {
                    System.out.println("Seat is taken");
                } 
                // reserves seat if not reserved
                else {
                    replaceWithX(numRes);
                    System.out.println("Seat successfully reserved");
                }
            }
            // prints new array
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                    System.out.print(stringArray[i][j] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is like this looks like this:

1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
22  23  24  25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32  33  34  35
Enter seat number to reserve: 1
Seat successfully reserved

X   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
22  23  24  25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32  33  34  35
Enter seat number to reserve: 2
Seat is taken

X   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
22  23  24  25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32  33  34  35
Enter seat number to reserve:

Can you guys give me tips on where the problem in the code is? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you not passing the seat number in `if (chkData()) {...` ?

Comment: Also, find some logic for the method `replaceWithX(int numRes)` using modula and divide

Comment: @ScaryWombat for the `if (chkData()) {.. ` should I add a way to detect if the input number has already been inputted before?

Comment: @ScaryWombat as for the `replaceWithX(int numRes)`  , I'm not really familiar with modula and divide as I've just started learning Java but can I ask where I can learn about that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: At the moment you are returning true, if any seats have been reserved.

Comment: Try writing some test code like `for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++) 
   System.out.printf("%d %d%n", i / 7, i % 7);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more cleaner by calculating row and column number from seat number, here is one way you can do it:

```
public class SeatReservation_Andaya {

    // create 2d array w/ 7 columns and 5 rows
    // create another array
    static String[][] stringArray = new String[5][7];

    // declare variables
    static int seatNum = 1;
    static int i, j;

    static void replaceWithX(int numRes) {
        // replaces the seat chosen with "X"
        int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7;
        int colNum = (numRes-1)%7;
        stringArray[rowNum][colNum] = "X";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create scanner tool
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // puts int array values into string
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                stringArray[i][j] = Integer.toString(seatNum);
                seatNum++;
            }
        }

        // prints the array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                System.out.print(stringArray[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // loops reservation system
        while (true) {
            // asks for seat number
            System.out.print("Enter seat number to reserve: ");

            // reads input
            int numRes = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());

            // check if input is invalid
            if (numRes > 35 || numRes <1) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID SEAT NUMBER");
            } else {
                // checks if seat is reserved
                int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7;
                int colNum = (numRes-1)%7;
                if (stringArray[rowNum][colNum].equals("X")) {
                    System.out.println("Seat is taken");
                }
                // reserves seat if not reserved
                else {
                    replaceWithX(numRes);
                    System.out.println("Seat successfully reserved");
                }
            }
            // prints new array
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                    System.out.print(stringArray[i][j] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).